# Table without side border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I want to be able to create table (ex. using TableLayout) without having border on its side. 
Aim is to achieve something like below:

[image]

I was trying something like this:

```
border.xml
```

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="0dp" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#123456" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the table layout (some example values for textView's):

```
  <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Months" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Number of Visits" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="January" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="1" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="Februrary" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

It displays as below - I cannot get the middle line between the columns:

[image]

How to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

hhmmm Pretty owsome. Below line of code will be helpfull for you.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="5dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Months" />

        <View android:layout_width="1dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000"
              android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Number of Visits" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="January" />

        <View android:layout_width="1dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000"
              android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Februrary" />

        <View android:layout_width="1dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000"
              android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And Don't forget to appreciate and like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new drawable with right border:

border_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:left="0dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="0dp" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#123456" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And use this drawable to your layout like below:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Months" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_right"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Number of Visits" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="January" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_right"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Februrary" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border_right"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

The Output of above code is like:

[image]